# como puedo realizar una consulta con tres tablas relacionadas?

Tags: mysql

estoy realizado la siguiente consulta: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me sale ese error ...

las tablas son las siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen, si es posible coloca un par de registros de ejemplo de las tablas involucradas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

muchas gracias amigo... ya resolví 
lo que la consulta quedaría

```
SELECT
  Identificacion,
  Nombres,
  Apellidos,
  Id_Acudiente,
  Nombres_Acudiente,
  Parentezco
FROM inscripciones,
  acudiente,
  parentezco,
  acudiente_x_estudiante
WHERE (acudiente_x_estudiante.Id_Estudiante_x_Acudiente = inscripciones.Identificacion)
    AND (acudiente_x_estudiante.Id_Acudiente_x_Acudiente = acudiente.Id_Acudiente)
    AND (acudiente_x_estudiante.Id_Parentezco_x_Acudiente = parentezco.Id_Parentezco)
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando las columnas de la tabla acudiente_x_estudiante, sin añadirla en la clausula FROM.